# Routing to virtual interface on Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, 16.04, server

I just created a virtual interface (VLAN 10) on my Ubuntu server; hosts from my network can reach the physical interface; however hosts on my network on VLAN 10 cannot reach the virtual interface IP. I conducted a tcpdump and can confirm the server is receiving the packet on physical interface; somehow it is not forwarding it to the virtual interface. The physical interface (ens33) is on an untagged VLAN.

Weirdly, when I check the ARP table on a computer on my network or the network switch, it knows about the mac address of the virtual interface IP (10.10.0.43.) So it appears ARP is working:

```
My_Home_Wall#show arp
Protocol  Address          Age (min)  Hardware Addr   Type   Interface
Internet  10.10.0.43             18   000c.294c.0aaf  ARPA   Vlan10
```

Pings from inside the Ubuntu server to the virtual interface IP work just fine:

```
admin@ubuntu:~$ ping 10.10.0.43
PING 10.10.0.43 (10.10.0.43) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.0.43: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.0.43: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.029 ms
```

What could I be missing? Few outputs from the server below:

```
admin@ubuntu:~$ nmcli device status
DEVICE    TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION
ens33     ethernet  connected  Ifupdown (ens33)
ens33.10  vlan      connected  ens33.10
lo        loopback  unmanaged  --

admin@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig
ens33     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:4c:0a:af
          inet addr:10.20.0.64  Bcast:10.20.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f135:7631:4bd8:96ad/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3064 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2529 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:469165 (469.1 KB)  TX bytes:427318 (427.3 KB)

ens33.10  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:4c:0a:af
          inet addr:10.10.0.43  Bcast:10.10.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe4c:aaf/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2269 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:355582 (355.5 KB)
```

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.20.0.120     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens33
0.0.0.0         10.20.0.120     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens33
10.10.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens33.10
10.20.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens33
```

P.S: I assigned the virtual interface statically because it wouldn't get an IP from DHCP. When looking at the debugs from my server, I see the dhcp request coming in to VLAN, it offers an IP address for that VLAN, the server receives the offer (I know this from a tcpdump) but it never sends back a request.

Comment: It seems you might be putting a lot of work into this. You are aware that 16.04 is EOL in April of this year?

Comment: Thanks. Are you suggesting that if I upgrade I shouldn’t run into this problem?

Comment: That may be the case, No I am not saying an upgrade WILL fix it I am just warning that you may have things to fix all over again after the needed upgrade in just a few weeks, Upgrade first and see if you still have the same issues.